# HTML5 canvas conversion - monitor pixel to canvas point

Tags: html5-canvas

As I haven't found anything about this I wonder if I missed a simple thing:

```
canvas#cvs1 {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}


var context = cvs1.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(16, 32);
context.lineTo(32, 32);
context.closePath();
```

If I draw a triangle onto the canvas the triangle is about 3x3 pixels (and not 32x32 like I thougth) so what do I miss that the coordinates from `context.lineTo(32, 32);` don't reflect the pixels from width/heigth of the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use CSS to resize the canvas. Resizing with CSS "shrinks" each pixel on the canvas and results in your mini-triangle.

```
// the canvas is 300px by 150px size by default
// This CSS causes each pixel to be squished in size to
//     32/300 wide and 32/150 high
canvas#cvs1 { width: 32px; height: 32px; }
```

Instead, resize the canvas element itself:

```
cvs1.width=32;
cvs1.height=32;
```